# What names are generated for property ivars without explicit declarations?

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, hook, cydia

This question is related to hooking with Mobile Substrate, but as long as you know Objective-C you probably can help.

I've got this class that I dumped from UIKit. Here is a piece of it:

```
@interface UIStatusBarItem : NSObject {
     int _type;
}
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) int type;
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) int leftOrder;
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) int rightOrder;
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) int priority;

...

@end
```

Naturally, if i wanted to set `int type` to, for example, 16, I would do:

```
MSHookIvar<int>(self, "_type") = 16;
```

From then on, `[self type]` will return 16. This much I know.

My problem is that I don't know what the compiler "names" the `int` where the values for `int leftOrder`, `int rightOrder`, and `int priority` are stored. I tried:

```
MSHookIvar<int>(self, "leftOrder")
```

but that's incorrect and crashes the phone.  All I really need to know is how these variables are auto-named if you don't specify it yourself. Thanks

*Also, I hate to sound like a prick, but please don't respond with just "don't do this, it's not safe." I know it's not, and that's why most of my products are in Cydia and not the App Store =P*

Comment: My guess is that eah one is named starting with underscore _xxxx. but you would need to add them to the implementation below. _type. One thing I do know is that you don't need the retain keyword in the property for int values as they as not nsobjects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backing ivars are typically named the same as the property. Without more details, I've no idea why that crashed. You can check at runtime what the names are, using [property_getAttributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101) from the Objective C runtime (having used `class_copyPropertyList` to get the properties from a class).

Also, not to sound too prickish myself, even in Cydia you shouldn't do fundamentally unsafe things. Software reliability for users is as important in a 3rd party app store as it is in the official one.

Comment: I just did this and printed out all of the vars are:

type Ti,R,N,V_type
leftOrder Ti,R,D,N
rightOrder Ti,R,D,N
priority Ti,R,D,N

Looks like they don't even have names.